# How to validate my contact form in PHP? Solution to my code

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a contact form on my website with required email field.
I am trying to validate the input field in PHP to avoid users submitting empty email field. I tried several tutorials but was unsuccessful so far. I would appreciate if anyone here can help me fix my code below

```
<?php
$recipient_email    = "info@example.com"; //recepient
$from_email         = "info@example.com";

if($_POST){

    $subject = 'Example.com';
    $from = "info@example.com";
    $to = "recipient@your-server.com";
    $name   = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $street = filter_var($_POST["strasse"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $tel    = filter_var($_POST["tel"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email  = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $name   = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $street = filter_var($_POST["strasse"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $email  = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $tel    = filter_var($_POST["tel"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

    $message_body =  "Message from $name\n";
    $message_body .=  "------------------------------\n";

    $message_body .=  "Name: $name\n";
    $message_body .=  "Street: $street \n";
    $message_body .=  "Email: $email \n";
    $message_body .=  "Telefon: $tel \n";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

    //message text
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body)); 
    exit;
}

$headers = "From:".$from_email."\r\n".  
            "Reply-To: ".$email. "\r\n" .
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$body = $message_body;
}

$sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
{       
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
}else{
    print 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.';  
    exit;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Now the code is sensibly formatted, do you see you have to many `}`

Comment: Isn't this just a simple `if`? `if(!$email) { /*show an error*/ } else { /* send e-mail */}` or similar?

Comment: It would also help if you told us what the problem is

Comment: The problem is some visitors to my site are sending me empty email fields, even though I specified that this is a required field in my HTML code required="required" I added a code as suggested by a user here the following code if(!$email) {
  print 'Your email is wrong.';
  exit;
} but what is happening is when user don't enter email it opens a new window that says your email is wrong. I want the error message to appear in the required email field Instead of opening in a new window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already checking your variables you just need simple if which will exit the code. After your filter_vars do this:

```
... start of your code

    $name   = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $street = filter_var($_POST["strasse"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $tel    = filter_var($_POST["tel"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email  = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $name   = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $street = filter_var($_POST["strasse"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $email  = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $tel    = filter_var($_POST["tel"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

if(!$email) {
  print 'Your email is wrong.';
  exit;
}

... continue with your code
```

Comment: I am sorry I am not very good with PHP. Are you saying i just need to add that bit and my code will work? thank you for your help

Comment: Yes. Add if(!$email) { .... under your variables test and it will prevent sending email if it's empty or wrong.

Comment: The problem is users are sending me empty email fields. They are bypassing client side email required field. That's why I want to validate my code on the server side

Comment: Yes. And this will not allow to continue in code execution if email is empty.

Comment: it worked, however when I didnt enter email, it took me to a new page saying "your email is wrong" is there a way to stay on same homepage and have a message in the email field itself saying "your email is wrong". Maybe something I can add to my HTML code? this is my HTML code for email field. <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*"/>

Comment: Hello. Answer I have posted is correct to your question. Please create another question if you have any furthere questions. Please mark it as correct if it answered what you have asked for. Thank you!

Comment: But I need to adjust the rest of the code as I explained above, could you help with that please?

Comment: There are multiple problems with it. You didn't show your html, where is your php included... etc. You can't ask people to give you full solution here. People will help you with your problematic code, they will not write whole solution for you.

Comment: I showed my HTML code to ask what can I add to it in order to make it work the way I intend to. I will post my my HTML in case you wish to help. Thank you again .     <h3 class="formtitle">Jetzt unverbindliche Offerte einholen!</h3>
  <form id="form1"   name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">                                                                                           

  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*"/>
<input disabled="disabled" id="submit" type="submit" value="Senden" name="button" class="submit" />

Comment: I'd compare the return of filter_var with false.  It's more explicit.

Comment: could you please show me how cause I am not very familiar with writing PHP Code. Thanks in advance